# Authenticated api calls from laravel session login. Is it possible?

Tags: ajax, laravel, api, authentication

So I'm just having an issue finding exactly what I'm looking for. So I am use to writing SPAs and managing auth that way. But I am working on a project where the user logs in with laravel session login, and then I need to make an API call that is authenticated and I can retrieve the user object from. Is this possible and safe?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible and safe. It is no less safe than any web login.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating API means, you are using frontend frameworks. Laravel default login use session for authentication, which is only accessed in server. So client ie frontend applications cant't access session.In this case Session authentication will not work.

you should use Token Authentication instead of session authentication. There is a package passport https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport in laravel. or use can use JWT https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth.

With Session Athentication, using ajax you can retrive auth user sth like this,

```
public function authInfo()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user)
        {
          $data = [
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'status' => ($user->verified) ? 1 : 0,
          ];
          return response()->json(["data" => $data, 'status' => "200"]);
        }else{
         return response()->json(["failed" => "failed", 'status' => "204"]);
        }
    }
```

and add route to hit this method

Comment: Thanks, I use Passport often. That's not the issue. I just wanted to know if you can login via session and make authenticated ajax calls

Comment: sure, you can do it. there is no threat with ajax call in my knowledge

Comment: I think you are missing the point. How do you retrieve the user?

Comment: @Jason Spick, i have edited by aswer to retrive currently login user detail

Comment: I'm assuming this answer is only possible with jwt. is that correct?

Comment: Nop, its just session. jwt, passport not required to do like this, try it once it solves your problem

Comment: are you using 'auth:api' middleware, it only work with auth middleware, for auth:api middleware you should use Token authentication instead of session authentication.